# Check if Workbench Content Has Published Revision

Tags: 7, rules, workbench

We are using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) for advanced Workbench notifications. However, we have a notification that needs to change depending on whether content actually has a previously published version or is entirely new content.

Does anyone know of a way, using  [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), to check for whether Workbench content has a published *revision*? (Note: **Not** whether the current revision is published.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this question is about D7 ...

#### Step 1 - Flag published revisions

Use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to flag Workbench content whenever a published revision gets created. The flag you'd want to use is a *global* flag. To actually flag such content, use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

#### Step 2 - Check if flagged

Adapt your existing Rule(s) (for advanced Workbench notifications) to take into account if your content has yes or no been flagged. To do so, you have a choice:

- Split your current Rules Action (for those notifications) in 2 Rules Components (in which you can use Rules Condition to check the flag).
- Use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module so that you can include the required Rules Condition(s), to check the status of the flag, within the Rules Actions of your existing rule.